# W3C validation error for 'email'

Tags: w3c-validation

I'm looking for help to validate the home page of the site www.ceramiche-civitacastellana.com.

I have managed to resolve all errors except 1:

in 913, defines the identifier ' email ', in the input field newsletter.

The identifier is usually repeated in the input field ' e-mail address ' login.
I know that there cannot be two identifiers are the same in the usual page, therefore the latter does not pass validation.

The solution is to assign a different id to one of the two, but I don't know how to do this. 
I could have directions or help for how to intervene and resolve the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the problem here. You can use any ID you like for the second field. Why don't you just use *login_email* as id? Maybe you mix up id and type? There is no rule that says you have to use email as id for an email-input..